# Whether to use text or BLOB data type in Cassandra for storing JSON content?

Tags: json, text, types, cassandra, blob

My requirement is to store the JSON response I receive on a REST call and retrieve it later from DB for some other purpose. DB we are having for this purpose is Cassandra. Which datatype to use for the column to store this JSON response? Text or BLOB ?

Comment: Blob is not a data type in Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `text`. I feel that `blob` should be used when the data doesn't really fit any of the standard types. Also `text` has the advantage of being readable (if being queried using `cqlsh` or something).

Comment: I observed that the select all query is timing out after inserting some values into the table. But I am able to get the values using primary key. For my case, I will query the table with primary key. But, do I need to worry about timeout when doing select all query. Will this be the case even with BLOB?

Comment: I don't think the choice of `text` vs `blob` for the same data will affect the result of the query.

Comment: There are three column in this table where I store three different JSON data. two columns will have data size up to 1MB and the third column size will be up to 2MB. When I do select * on this table it is timing out, this is expected right?